# Cancel attached backup service

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird

My software has to make database backups and one of the expected features is that this backup can be canceled.

As I can think of, I have three options:

- Use a component, such as TIBBackupService
- Programmatically call gbak using ShellExecute or so
- Programmatically call to the service using GDS32.dll API

I tried the first one and even if I cancel it the service keeps running (the backup file is built until the end and all resoureces keep unchanged).

The second option smells to me and I don´t think I´ll be able to abort the operation as well.

The third option will cost some hours and so I´d like to know:

- Is there a way to abort the backup operation using the first option?
- The third option is viable? If yes, the operation will be abortable?
- Is Firebird backup operation cancelable at all?

Thanks

Comment: Is the firebird backup operation cancellable at all?

Comment: You can easily cancel the execution of gbak with a call to TerminateProcess. It's not pretty but it will get the job done!

Comment: @David: If it's not a local connection that won't help at all, as the backup will continue to run on the server.

Comment: @mghie Won't the broken connection result in the server giving up, at some point?

Comment: @Ricardo: If you have the database on the local system and are on Firebird 2 then look into the nbackup tool. Its ability to create incremental backups might make it feasible to do without that feature.

Comment: @David: Not really, see http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq63. I don't think terminating the server is really the way to go...

Comment: When you manually run gbak at the command line, and then terminate it (with Ctrl+C), does the backup stop?

Comment: @mghie that link suggests that it is not worth aborting a remote backup

Comment: @Rob Yes. The same as when I kill my delphi process. But killing the process is not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PS: You didn't mention the Firebird version you are using.

1) gbak is "normal" application that connects to database, read all information, and write it to backup file. Restore process is the inverse.

2) When you use ServicesAPI to do backup (option 1 and 3, in your example), Firebird will start an "internal" version of gbak to do the job.

For any of the options, if you are using Firebird 2.1, you can run a "delete from mon$statements where mon$attachment_id = " from a different connection. This will stop the backup process. With FB 2.5, you can even drop the gbak connection, doing a "delete from mon$attachments where...".

You can find what is the gbak attachment id looking the mon$remote_process in mon$attachments table.